# Sequence of Constructors and Destructors when base class type member variable is initialized through initializer list

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor

while I'm writing some code regarding base class/derived class type variables, I encountered this somewhat weird situation. It goes like this :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A Con" << endl; }
    virtual ~A() { cout << "A Dec" << endl; }
};
class B : A {
public:
    A a;
    B(A _a) : a(_a) { 
        cout << "B Con" << endl;
    }
    virtual ~B() { cout << "B Dec" << endl; }    
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b(a);
}
```

I declared base class(A) type member variable in derived class(B), and then above code gives me this result :

[image]

OK, so first constructor and last constructor would be for 'a' in main function.
But what about the others? why destructors are called 5 times while constructors are only called 3?

My Guess is :

```
A Con -> a in main()
A Con -> b in main() (base class constructor)
B Con -> b in main() (derived class constructor)
A Dec -> temporary value passed in B(A _a) : a(_a), copy constructor is called...
B Dec -> b in main() (derived class destructor)
A Dec -> member variable in B class (A a;)
A Dec -> b in main() (base class destuctor)
A Dec -> a in main()
```

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: You're missing the copy constructor for `A` which is what's actually getting called. You'll get fewer of them by passing `a` by reference rather than by value

Comment: Also, the name of the function invoked when destroying an instance of a class is "destructor" not "deconstructor".   If you're going to ask questions about C++, at least use the same nomenclature for things that the C++ standard does, rather than making up your own non-words.

Comment: @Peter Oops, there was a typo in the question. I used 'destructor' all the way after that. Thanks for letting me know that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
B(A _a) : a(_a) { 
    cout << "B Con" << endl;
}
```

calls `A`'s copy constructor, which you have not defined and which does not print anything. Add this to `A`:

```
A(A const&) { cout << "A Con (Copy)" << endl; }
```

And while you're at it, you may want `A(A&&)`, `A& operator=(A const&)` and `A& operator=(A&&)` as well.

Comment: Since `B` is also derived from `A` (i.e. it has both a base and a member of type `A`), the constructor you describe is actually equivalent to `B(A _a) : A(), a(_a) {cout << "B con" << endl;}`.   There is also a wrinkle that an implementation is permitted to (or, in later standards, in some cases, required to) elide temporaries/copies.